# How to use ImageMagick mogrify on file names contained in a text file?

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I want to run a mogrify command on images whose filenames are listed in a text file and I can't find a related answer on here.

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: Mogrify does not work on filename nor a text file input. You will have to write a script loop over each image in your file and process with convert.

Comment: strange, seems such an obvious need for this kind of operation. Thx

Comment: mogrify is designed to process all files in a folder with option to limit to certain file types. It does not filter on names other than by file type.

Comment: See GeeMack's solution. I did not know that could be done.

Answer (score 2):

To use a text list of images as input to ImageMagick you can just add a "@" at the beginning of the name of the text file like this...

```
mogrify -resize 480x @mylist.txt
```

If any of the filenames in the list have spaces in them, make sure they are enclosed in double quotes. So "mylist.txt" would look something like this...

```
"image one.jpg"
"image two.jpg"
"another image.jpg"
"and another one.jpg"
...
```

Edited to add:

The suggestion by **webbernaut** to cat and pipe the image list into the mogrify command should work if you modify it a bit. After the pipe, in the mogrify command you read in the image list with a "-", but ImageMagick still wants to work it like a text list, so the dash has to be preceded by an "@" like this...

```
cat mylist.txt | mogrify -resize 480x @-
```

Comment: Thank, GeeMack. I did not know one could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GeeMack , I finally run :
`du -hms *.jpg | sort -nr | head -n30 | awk '{print $2}' | mogrify -quality 70 -verbose @-`
to compress 30 (head -n30) largest jpg files in my current folder

Answer (score -1):

Using the ImageMagick command line tool something like this. Below is how to glob a folder.

```
magick mogrify -resize 256x256 *.jpg
```

You can try a simple one liner in your terminal if using linux or unix OS (untested)

```
cat filename.txt | magick mogrify -resize 256x256
```

Comment: `cat filename.txt | magick mogrify -resize 256x256` doesn't work